# Realm: get notified on new insertion / update of object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying out Realm.io on my Swift project. The insertion and update of objects are pretty straightforward, but here comes a problem: I am not able to catch a new object insertion/update notification.

What I want to achieve is simple, I save a list of objects in Realm. And upon app start/refresh, the app will request a new list of objects from remote server and then perform `realm.add(objects, update:true)` (I've set `id` as the object's primary key so that the same objects will not be duplicated), then the UI end of my app should be notified whenever there's a new object, or any existing objects have been updated.

I've tried using `realm.addNotificationBlock(_:)` but it's called every time with a `RLMRealmDidChangeNotification` event, even though there is no new object/update.

How do I achieve this?

Edit: code sample

```
public class DataStorageManager {
var token : NotificationToken?
static let sharedInstance = DataStorageManager ()

public func saveListA(list: [A]?, realm:Realm) {
    self.token = realm.addNotificationBlock({ (notification, realm) -> Void in
        print("database changed")
    })
    if list?.count > 0 {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(list!, update:true)
        }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the Objective-C version of Realm? Also, some code samples of what you have so far will help.

Comment: @caseynolan I'm actually using a swift version of Realm. Sorry if the previous method definition confuses you. I've added the code sample in the edit.

Comment: @tropicalfish Unfortunately, such notifications have not been supported yet. We will be adding fine grained notifications in a future release. The most commonly requested feature has been changelist notification for queries. Once we support this you can register for a notification on an RLMArray to get a list of objects which were added, removed, or changed in position during a transaction. The issue is tracked by https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/601

Answer (score 1):

You should call `addNotificationBlock` only once and not everytime you call `saveListA`. So you could move it to the `DataStorageManager`'s `init` method.

But you wrote that you want to update your UI whenever the list is updated, so instead of having the token inside your `DataStorageManager` class you could directly add the `NotificationToken` as a property to your `UIViewController` class and call `addNotificationBlock` in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. Then you can directly update your UI inside the notification block.

EDIT:

If you only want to update your UI when certain data gets updated you cannot use Realm's notification system (which sends a notification everytime any data is changed).

You can do one of the following

1. Use KVO on your Realm objects. This is described in the [Realm Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#key-value-observation)
2. Send your own `NSNotification` whenever the data is updated that needs a refresh of your UI. So in your case you can send an `NSNotification` everytime your list gets changed in `saveListA`. Then you register your view controller as an observer to that notification and update your UI whenever you receive that notification.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried doing that, but I found that the notification is fired everytime there's a change in database, i.e. on saveListB, saveListC as well. There doesn't seem to be a way to know which data got changed. Perhaps a self-built notification system is a way to go.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is the way the notification system is built. It fires a notification everytime a write action is performed. Regardless of what data was changed. See my updated answer for two suggestions on how to get informed only when certain data gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you should fetch the desired objects somewhere you want to hold them (like your data manager or view controller), getting `Results` object and subscribe to this `Results` change.

Please refer to https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications.

It doesn't matter where the object would be changed as long as you hold to that notifications token.

The downside is, currently "modifications" array always include every "touched" element, regardless of if there had been any changes at all. It is considered a bug, but no progress there since August '17.
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3489

For now, I compare modifications manually after getting the notification.